# TinyMce - it is possible to disable Rich Text?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In my app I have TinyMce plugin. Now I need to at any time switch with richtext to plaintext. In this [example](http://oregonstate.edu/cws/training/book/export/html/210) I suspect that it can be done.

The only question is how? I saw a solution with the addition selectbox and js functions. Is there no mechanism built-in TinyMCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is shutdown tinymce and show the tinymce route element (the div for which you have created the tinymce editor). The textarea is editable and shows the full HTML-Contents of the Editor.

To shut down your tinymce use

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').remove();
```

To make the underlying textarea visisble:

```
document.getElementById('your_editor_id').setAttribute('style', visibility:visible; display:block;);
```

or using jQuery

```
$('#your_editor_id').css('visibility', 'visible').css('display', 'block');
```

**Update**:

This works with Tinymce 4. Use the setup parameter

```
setup: function(ed)
{
  ed.on('click', function(e){
    tinymce.execCommand('mceToggleEditor', false, 'your editor_id');
  });
}
```

Here is a working tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Fnfaab

Comment: OK. Probably I poorly explained. It's my case: [link](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/). I ask if there's a built-in button to switch between richtext/plaintext. It is known that it can be programmed but I'm looking for something built-in.

Comment: See my updated answer. Plus, you can view the real HTML-code using the code plugin. You can also edit the HTML code there.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Thariama

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tinymce API and call the Formatter class like this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove();  // no format name==all formats
```